# Alternative for https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0

Tags: google-api, google-search-api, google-image-search

These days I noticed that Google Search API for images which I'm using on my project is no longer available, e.g.

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=apple

returns

```
{  
  "responseData": null,
  "responseDetails": "This API is no longer available.",
  "responseStatus": 403
}
```

What should I use instead for search images?

**UPD:** I'm not strictly tied to Google Search, any other alternative **images search** API is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Api is longer available ,you need to use google custom search api. you can make limited calls on free version. For unlimited google search api calls you need to pay.

Make a custom google custom search api.
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/customsearch

Comment: "Free quota: 100 requests/day" - this sucks.

Comment: There is no other alternative for you for google search .

Comment: I'm not strictly tied to Google Search, any other alternative _images_ search API is acceptable.

Comment: Good,Instagram apis are also closing soon

Answer (score 0):

The [Yahoo Boss API](https://developer.yahoo.com/boss/search/) is a pretty close substitute. It's not free though ($1.80 per 1,000 queries). And the results aren't quite as good as Google.